# Hold connection between iOS and Mac, even if App is in Background (as VOIP?)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, iostream, bonjour

I need to connect an iOS Device to a computer/mac. It's necessary to take this connection alive, even if the app goes in background mode. I know that the normal life cycle of a multitasking app will cut the connection at unknown time. Now my idea was to declare the app as an VOIP-App, so that I can use the SignOfLive to send signal to the PC. Is that possible?

Please note that I'm only asking if it's possible, not if apple would like this way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible to set any app as a VoIP app and enable keep-alives.  But, Apple will reject the app and the keep-alive trigger interval has a 600 second minimum and can only run for 30-seconds.

The keep-alive is limited and is really intended for sending SIP registrations.

Why don't you describe what you are trying to accomplish and someone may be able to offer a better solution?

The voip setting will also allow the app to listen for network traffic, while in the background.  Or, if you just need to be able to have a network process finish, any app can continue to run in the background for up to 10 minutes.